# Ios app strange rotation behaviour after iOS 8 SDK update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8

I've been developing an iPad app which was working fine until i updated my Xcode to version 6 and my iPad to iOS 8.The problem i am encountering now is that when i change the orientation of my iPad i can catch the event but the views do not rotate accordingly.To be specific in my iPad with iOS 7 app rotates itself size of the views stay the same; for example if i start the app in portrait mode and change rotation to landscape there is a space on the right side of the uiview.In my iPad with IOS 8 views do not even rotate itself and stay the same all the time.I'm not using auto layout and app used to work like charm before IOS 8 SDK release.I need your help on finding articles and cause of the problems.Thanks in advance

probably the cause of problem is this line but i need to have this because otherwise my app won't release uiwebview from memory.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.window.rootViewController=self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotation handling has changed in iOS 8. Methods such as `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` are now deprecated and replaced by `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`. Depending on how you're handling rotations in your app, you may have to make changes in your code to adapt to the new methods. Check chapter "Handling view rotation" in the [UIViewController reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW47)

Comment: i just realised -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.window.rootViewController=self;
}
causes the problem.if i don't use this line the autosize and rotation works.but then my uiwebview is not released from memory.am i missing something?